# Occurrence of at least one event.

Tags: probability, independence

I am new to probability and its concepts trying to answer the following question.

Let $F, G$ and $H$ be Pairwise Independent events such that $P(F) = P(G) = P(H) = 1/3$ and $P(F \& G \& H) = 1/4$. Then, the probability that at least one event among $F, G$ and $H$ occurs.

I understand that $P(\text{Event occurring at least once}) = 1 - P(\text{Event not occurring at all})$ but I am failing to apply this in the question above.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts, and you can begin a paragraph with `>` to make a block quote.

Comment: Thanks. :) I will keep that in mind going forward.

Comment: The numbers in the problem don't make sense (or am I missing something?): Since $F$ and $G$ are independent, $P(F\cap G)=\frac13\cdot\frac13 = \frac19$, but this is less than $P(F\cap G\cap H)$ given in the problem.  This seems like a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event that at least one of $F,G,H$ occur is equivalent to $F\cup G\cup H$ (that is, only one of the three possible events occur, or any two of the events occur, or all three occur simultaneously).

By the [inclusion-exlusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), we have

$$\mathbb P(F\cup G\cup H)=\mathbb P(F)+\mathbb P(G)+\mathbb P(H)-\mathbb P(F\cap G)-\mathbb P(G\cap H)-\mathbb P(F\cap H)+\mathbb P(F\cap G\cap H)$$

Given that $F,G,H$ are pairwise independent, we know that

$$\mathbb P(F\cap G)=\mathbb P(F)\mathbb P(G)$$
$$\mathbb P(F\cap H)=\mathbb P(F)\mathbb P(H)$$
$$\mathbb P(G\cap H)=\mathbb P(G)\mathbb P(H)$$

and we know $\mathbb P(F\cap G\cap H)$, so we have everything we need to show that

> $$\mathbb P(F\cup G\cup H)=\frac{11}{12}$$

Comment: Yes. I figured the pairwise independent part but never thought to put it in the formula. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are three events, each of which can happen or not.  That gives rise to $2^3=8$ combinations of events which could happen.  You are correct that you want to subtract the chances that at least one happens from $1$ to get your answer.  You are given four of the eight in the question, so you need to find the probability of three more, which are the cases where two happen and one does not.  The statement of pairwise independence is the key to this.  What do you know about independent events?

Comment: Hi Ross, Nothing has been said about the independence of the events individually. Only pairwise independence has been stated.